# How to put data from v4l2 to a c++ vector

Tags: c++, v4l2

I'm currently trying to read video from a MJPEG UVC webcam using C++.
Using [this tutorial](https://jwhsmith.net/2014/12/capturing-a-webcam-stream-using-v4l2/), I'm able to retrieve a JPEG image and to save it on disk. Now, I try to use the JPEG image data without writing it on disk ; I want to use a C++ vector to store it, but I can't find how to achieve that .

As far as I understand, the tutorial maps a memory segment that v4l2 uses to store webcam data in memory :

```
struct v4l2_buffer bufferinfo;
memset(&bufferinfo, 0, sizeof(bufferinfo));

bufferinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
bufferinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
bufferinfo.index = 0;

if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
    perror("VIDIOC_QUERYBUF");
    exit(1);
}

void* buffer_start = mmap(
    NULL,
    bufferinfo.length,
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED,
    fd,
    bufferinfo.m.offset
);
```

This memory segment is populated by v4l2 when we send some command :

```
if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
    perror("VIDIOC_QBUF");
    exit(1);
}

// The buffer's waiting in the outgoing queue.
if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
    perror("VIDIOC_QBUF");
    exit(1);
}
```

To finish, the memory is written to the disk using write function :

```
int jpgfile;
if((jpgfile = open("/tmp/myimage.jpeg", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660)) < 0){
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
}
write(jpgfile, buffer_start, bufferinfo.length);
close(jpgfile);
```

But how can I copy this memory segment into a vector ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinterpret the `void *` as a `char *` to obtain the raw data:

```
char *char_buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer_start);

std::vector<char> jpegdata{char_buffer, char_buffer + bufferinfo.length};
```

(This uses the "iterator pair" overload of the vector constructor.)

You might consider using `std::string` instead:

```
std::string jpegdata{reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer_start), bufferinfo.length};
```

(The `std::string` approach may wind up being faster; the constructor will likely `memcpy()` or use some other blitting technique to copy data more efficiently than the iterator-based vector template constructor.)

Comment: Thank you ! It works fine ! But I can't use the string version because I use jpeg data with OpenCV Mat structure, which only has a constructor from vector.

Comment: Shame. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a template constructor that would work with any container that contains chars.